# Convert Slack messages to Report Charts

Tags: bots, analytics, slack, slack-commands

I have created a slack bot that sends out a message upon every sale my products do.
The message format is the same, the only difference is the name of the product, the price and the time that sale occured.

Im wondering how can I sync those messages to a report that can be filtered in a third party app or place (without using Google Analytics) - something like mapping name of the product to be categorized, etc.